# Why would the Vashta Nerada accept the Doctor's offer in Forest of the Dead?

Tags: doctor-who

His threat was pretty awesome. yeah. But it was also very blank. First, he clearly wasn't protected from them, they could easily eat him. Second, he was offering them a forest, but what would they do with it if they don't have any food source?

Comment: This is, honestly, a lot of different questions.  Try to trim it down some.

Comment: @Radhil I've done that, how do i put it off hold?

Comment: Just editing it did your part.  It gets put in a review queue, other users will check it out, and vote on it, pretty much the same process that put it on hold.

Comment: I just saw this episode last night :) - I was wondering the same thing, but then the Doctor did say look him up... so when they found out that the Doctor can be unforgiving about losing people they probably just accepted the offer for self preservation.

Comment: *they could easily eat him* **And** the Daleks could easily exterminate him. Somehow practice seems to diverge from theory.

Answer (score 5):

Fear.

The Doctor might not actually have had anything able to keep them from just eating him - but they don't necessarily *know* that. They have no way to.

This is the man they have on record as having survived numerous "deaths" before as well as having wiped out *entire species.* Someone immensely dangerous who keeps to his threats.

So, they evidently just came to the conclusion that it wasn't worth the risk of trying, lest they end up like one of his many, *many* past foes.

As for the food: Given on Earth they apparently mostly eat road kill (and only the occasional lost human), they apparently don't actually need to eat anywhere near as much as they did at the library. So, it might take a while for that to become an actual issue for them - as opposed to the immediate danger they were presented with then and there.

Comment: "I am the doctor, and you are in the biggest library in the universe.... Look me up". They have way to know that the doctor IS able to do something to keep them from just eating him

Comment: @dna I meant as in they don't know he doesn't currently have anything at that precise moment - and hence fear will make them think he does, with what all the books will say about all the times he did. If that hopefully makes sense.